# What does it mean "Microsoft SQL 2010 R2" as an application requirement?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this terrible doubt of windows and hope someone of you might know what is it.

I bought a contability software (here in mexico there are few providers cause they are regulated), the thing is the seller is telling me some requirements for the computer which one of them is to have "Microsoft SQL 2010 R2" literally thats what it says. I have looked for this in google and I've got some microsoft links but they does not say literally what Im looking for:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Can someone tell me where to download that package and verify its installed correctly? Thanks.

Comment: "Microsoft SQL 2010 R2" doesn’t make any sense. The developers or the retailer should be giving you more information than this, have you tried going back to them?

Comment: I assume they want you to install a Microsoft SQL   Server instance in order to host a database in. You can download MS SQL Express from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18914 TBH it’s quite an old version now so I’m surprised they don’t recommend a later version.  Once you have created a SQL instance I assume you select it during the installation. E.g computername\sqlexpress , where sqlexpress is the name of the instance to host the databases in.

Comment: I'd reach out to the vendor and/or reseller of this product and verify specifically what you need to ensure someone is not telling you something incorrectly referencing a document with a typo, etc. I'd get on the phone and talk with some people about this before just assuming or guessing as they should know for sure since this is a product they develop, maintain, and/or support as something doesn't sound right even though it literally says that, that does not mean that is not 100% accurate so pressure them into verifying and telling you exactly what this means or in required in its place.